# Is it possible to get command line output from a UWP application

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app, uwp

I know how to start a UWP (windows store) application from the command line, using

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\<appid>!App
```

But if i do that, the command line returns to the prompt immediately and awaits new input. Is there a way to bind to the process and get some text output?

More generally, I am trying to diagnose an application failing to start.

Comment: Maybe try creating a batch script with the command to run the application and use "pause" at the end of the script. It will keep the console open after the first line executes. Not sure if it will output errors though, its worth a shot.

Comment: Try using the protocol for your app. EG `Calculator:\\ ` in Run dialog or `start calculator:\\ ` at command prompt.

Comment: Also see (by searching is settings) *View Reliability History* or *Problem Reports*.

Comment: That is to get error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Windows application, including UWP application, is either built for
console or GUI interface.

The difference is profound, starting with the application's
entry-point (main versus WinMain), the libraries that are
linked-to and more.

There is no way to force a GUI application to issue output to the
console if it has not been programmed for it.
The GUI application would need to be programmed
to actively attach itself to the console and write on it, in addition
to its GUI output.

In conclusion: If the UWP application doesn't expose an option for
console writing, then you cannot force it to.

For more information see for example the article
[Create a Universal Windows Platform console app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp).

Comment: Thanks I feared as much